# How to fix the "undefined reference to ‘_imp__*’" when I use cmake ("-G"MinGW Makefiles") with boost.python project

Tags: python, c++, boost, makefile

I am getting the error above when trying to build the project with boost.python use -G"MinGW Makefiles", how can I do to fix it?

And this is my machine configuration:
win7-64; mingw64; python2.7-64bit; boost-_1.51

### This is the err:

```
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NotImplementedStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `__imp_PyCFunction_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to `__imp_PyInt_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyInt_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1b3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyLong_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1c3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyBool_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1d3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyFloat_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyString_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyUnicode_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `__imp_PyComplex_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x243): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x5b7): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x5e3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x90e): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0xad0): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_AttributeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0xbf3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyInt_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1389): undefined reference to `__imp_PyComplex_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x13e5): undefined reference to `__imp_PyFloat_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1a13): undefined reference to `__imp_PyFloat_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1a83): undefined reference to `__imp_PyFloat_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1af3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyFloat_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1e19): undefined reference to `__imp_PyComplex_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1e75): undefined reference to `__imp_PyFloat_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1eb9): undefined reference to `__imp_PyComplex_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1f15): undefined reference to `__imp_PyFloat_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3694): undefined reference to `__imp_PyLong_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x36b7): undefined reference to `__imp_PyLong_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3714): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3734): undefined reference to `__imp_PyTuple_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3754): undefined reference to `__imp_PyString_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3903): undefined reference to `__imp_PyType_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3914): undefined reference to `__imp_PyProperty_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3977): undefined reference to `__imp_PyType_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3cdf): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3cf0): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_AttributeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3de3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3e4f): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3e8a): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3f33): undefined reference to `__imp_PyType_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x3f97): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x4021): undefined reference to `__imp_PyList_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x411c): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x4482): undefined reference to `__imp_PyLong_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x4b05): undefined reference to `__imp_PyProperty_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x4c68): undefined reference to `__imp_PyProperty_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x5033): undefined reference to `__imp_PyType_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x50b6): undefined reference to `__imp_PyBaseObject_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x5573): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x5593): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x55b3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x55c7): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_StopIteration'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x55ce): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x55f3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x56a3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_AttributeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x59c6): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x5e8b): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x5fa3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x608e): undefined reference to `__imp_PyList_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x6296): undefined reference to `__imp_PyList_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x64c9): undefined reference to `__imp_PyList_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0xef26): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0xf156): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0xf386): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0xf5ae): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0xf7ae): undefined reference to `__imp_PyList_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0xf9b6): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0xfba3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_AttributeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x116e6): undefined reference to `__imp_PyMethod_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x117b3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x11c49): undefined reference to `__imp_PyComplex_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x11e19): undefined reference to `__imp_PyComplex_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x11ffc): undefined reference to `__imp_PyComplex_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x12774): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x12e58): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_ImportError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x14433): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_OverflowError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x145f3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_OverflowError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x149e8): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_OverflowError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x14de8): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_OverflowError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x14ebf): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x155e2): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x15920): undefined reference to `__imp_PyModule_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x15be3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x15c23): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x15c43): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x160ab): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x160ce): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1651f): more undefined references to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct' follow
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x165e4): undefined reference to `__imp_PyType_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x16b99): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x16c13): undefined reference to `__imp_PyType_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x18165): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x185ec): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x18c0a): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x18cdb): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x18e2f): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x18e65): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x18eb0): more undefined references to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct' follow
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x191ef): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x195ef): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1961b): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1a003): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1ac73): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1dc99): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1dce2): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1dd85): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1dd8c): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1ded3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1deef): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1e28c): more undefined references to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct' follow
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x1eadc): undefined reference to `__imp_PyDict_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x211ff): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x21322): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x219e7): undefined reference to `__imp_PyClass_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x21ab0): undefined reference to `__imp_PyStaticMethod_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x21ac7): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x220d3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2213d): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x22717): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x22829): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x229b2): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x22ec2): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x23232): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x23690): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_ReferenceError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x23707): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x23874): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x25d73): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x25db7): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x25e60): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x28f74): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x29d4c): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x29fb1): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x29fc4): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2a0ef): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2a6f7): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2af48): undefined reference to `__imp_PyType_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2b3ad): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2b3db): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2bb77): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2bc33): undefined reference to `__imp_PyType_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2bc3a): undefined reference to `__imp_PyInt_Type'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2c3e8): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2c42d): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_ValueError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2c458): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2c483): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_OverflowError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2c4e9): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj):boostpy.cpp:(.text+0x2c72e): undefined reference to `__imp_Py_InitModule4'
d:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(boostpy.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0x38 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [main.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: In Addition, when I build it with -G"NMake Makefiles", it works well.